# How to pass events from parent to child component?

Tags: javascript, angular, events, output

How to pass object (which contains event) from parent to child component and how to emit @Output to that event from child to parent component.

Parent Compoent

ts file:

```
Obj = { 'event': 'onSelect($event)'}; 
onSelect(val){console.log('from child to parent')}
```

html file:

```
<child-component [Obj]="Obj"></child-component>
```

Child Component

How to emit/trigger action, which was sent from `Obj`.

Comment: Either it is an object or JSON: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Answer (score 1):

[EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) is what you're looking for

Child TS

```
@Output onSelect: EventEmitter<Object> = new EventEmitter();

select(){
  // myObject is object you want to send to parent
  onSelect.emit(myObject);
}
```

Child HTML

```
<a (click)="select()">Select this</a>
```

Parent HTML

```
<child-block [onSelect]="onChildSelect($event)">
```

Parent TS

```
//obj will contain object you've sent from your child 
onChildSelect(obj: Object){
   //your code
}
```